# highlighting text in ipython notebook with multiple tabs/notebooks

Tags: copy-paste, jupyter-notebook, highlighting

This problem is driving be crazy for a while - when I use ipython notebook with a few tabs/notebooks open I can highlight text only in one tab (the first notebook I opened) but not in any other notebook. If I try to mark a block of code in the rest of the notebooks it just wouldn't stick. 
This makes a copy+paste of code snippets btw. notebooks very annoying.

Another peculiarity is that the problem exists only 99% of the time and I couldn't find any consistency related to other tabs/SW/sites/browsers I'm using.

Settings (from chrome://version/):

**Google Chrome**   39.0.2171.95 (Official Build)

**Revision**    86b48442d063e82f94969f5439badf11c9baeacc-refs/branch-heads/2171@{#461}

**OS**  Linux

**Blink**   537.36 (@186555)

**JavaScript**  V8 3.29.88.17

**Flash**   16.0.0.235

**User Agent**  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36

**Command Line**    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --manual-enhanced-bookmarks --flag-switches-end http://127.0.0.1:8889/

Any idea? no one I know experienced this.
Thanks!

Comment: What version of IPython do you have ?

Comment: I have 1.1.0 installed